# What does a gap/broken line mean in IntelliJ Git graph?

Tags: intellij-idea, revision-graph

Have a look at this screenshot. Why is the graph broken up between the two nodes?

[image: Screenshot shows git graph in IntelliJ 2021.2 Ultimate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gap between commits means that there is a part of a history that does not match a filter criterion. Once you remove your filters you should see commits that are "hidden" by this gap.

Comment: Indeed. I wasn't even aware that I had set any filters.